# RoR: Devise: Email confirmation on heroku gives Connection refused error

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, email, heroku

so, in my production.rb file, I have the name of my app as the host:

```
  config.action_mailer.default_url_options = { :host => 'comsat.heroku.com' }
```

But, after I try registering, it says:

```
2011-08-14T05:47:00+00:00 app[web.1]: Sent mail to aoeuaoeu[fake]@gmail.com (3047ms)
2011-08-14T05:47:00+00:00 app[web.1]: Completed 500 Internal Server Error in 3412ms
2011-08-14T05:47:00+00:00 app[web.1]: 
2011-08-14T05:47:00+00:00 app[web.1]: Errno::ECONNREFUSED (Connection refused - connect(2)):
```

=\

What do I do?

Comment: Sendgrid solved my problem (see selected answer)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try sendgrid: http://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/sendgrid